# Can't Import ViewController into Provider in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I can't import my view controller to use in a provider in Ionic 2.

```
import { ModalController, ViewController, NavController } from "ionic-angular";

@Injectable()
export class DynamicModal<T extends IHasId> {

    modalOptions: DynamicModalOptions<T>;

    constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController, public viewCtrl: ViewController)
```

When I try it this way it gives me an error:

> No provider for ViewController

View Controllers work fine when injected into pages, but I would like to encapsulate all of my creation and dismiss logic so i do not have to rewrite it each time for ever place I use that modal.

How can I inject view controller into a modal?

Comment: ViewController is not something you place in providers array. That is normally where you place services...

Comment: @JGFMK do you have an example

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/ Although it's Ionic2, this video should help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5iGAAypGBA - Joshua Morony has a lot of useful videos when you are starting out with Ionic.

Comment: @JGFMK I've looked at that several times it does not show you how to register your view controller

Comment: @JGFMK thanks for the video i'll watch it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting the view controller injected in you can include it in your modal options instead:

```
export class DynamicModalOptions<T extends IHasId>
{
    entity: T;
    //other properties
    viewCtrl: ViewController;
}
```

Now when you dismiss you can just grab the view controller from your options

```
close() {
    this.modalOptions.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    this.modalOptions = null;
}
```

Since you are using a provider remember to clear out your modal options so that they're not in this here next time the provider is injected.

Comment: Thanks, for your contribution, granted some of that knowledge would be good,  but Can you provide a simple example of ViewController being injected?  Or just an example of a modal that is getting dismissed properly

Comment: That Joshua Morony video covers all that and with a ModalController. Have a watch through the video. He has a blog too. If you are lucky you might find a link to some source zipped up. Haven't looked. Try Googling "Passing Data Between Pages in Ionic 2 Joshua Morony"

Comment: Okay, I see my issue now, but I don't know How to fix it, I want to create a provider which automatically encapsulates the logic for modal creation

Comment: A provider is normally a service - that does things like call out to HTTP to load/save data. It can be for network stuff too like connected to Wifi on a mobile etc. You might use it to do pagination too.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to encapsule my creation logic etc, so I can be really lazy I think that's the issue, Viewcontroller can only be easily injected in a page

Comment: thanks for you help.  I took the liberty of updating your answer since you've helped me out so much

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare it in the `app.module.ts`, all you need is to import and declare it in the class constructor:

```
import { ViewController } from "ionic-native";

export class DynamicModal<T extends IHasId> {
  constructor(private viewCtrl: ViewController) {}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a bad edit, but I tried that way and it does not work, It cannot resolve the view controller when I try it that way

Comment: It may be a problem with your class declaration, I'm not familiar with that syntax and I couldn't find that class type declaration in the Typescript docs. Shouldn't it be `export class DynamicModal extends IHasId {`?

Comment: No It's a generic modal, Whose type inherits from an iterface with an id